# No puedo abrir QDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Estoy haciendo una `QMainWindow` que llama a un `QDialog`, al ejecutar el `QDialog` abre sin problemas pero al colocar el código para que abra desde la `QMainWindow` haciendo click en el botón me arroja el siguiente error>

> ```
> C:\Users\marco\Downloads\Python\PyQt\Condominio>python menuppal.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "menuppal.py", line 29, in dialogo
>     dialog = Dialog()
> NameError: name 'Dialog' is not defined
> ```

Este es el código de la ventana principal:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\marco\Downloads\Python\PyQt\condominio\menuppal.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from listageneral import *
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def dialogo(self, checked=None):
        if checked==None: return
        dialog = Dialog()
        dialog.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        dialog.exec_()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(714, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 661, 401))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        self.listgen = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.listgen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 75, 23))
        self.listgen.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listgen"))
        self.listgen.clicked.connect(self.dialogo)      
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.listgen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lista General", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Consulta", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hola Marco, tu clase `Dialog` debería heredar de `QtGui.QDialog` pero no tienes implementada la clase `Dialog` en tu código o en caso contrario instanciar directamente `dialog = QtGui.QDialog()`. Por otro lado `Ui_Dialog()` debe ser una clase que implementa el diseño, generalmente resultado de convertir un archivo `.ui` (QTDessigner) a `.py` ¿Es tu`listageneral.py` ese archivo?

Comment: Si listageneral.py es el archivo del QDialog que intento abrir. por si solo abre, el problema esta cuando intento llamarlo desde la MainWindow. Pero ya con la linea de codigo que me has enviado he resuelto. Muchas Gracias. Ya abre sin problemas.